# Sending textarea text to datagrid as object

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

I would like a text area that holds multiple strings to send its values to an array and the array to convert the string to an object. The objects then populate a datagrid. I can't really figure out where to go from here:

```
var arrayString:String = myTextArea.text;
var newArray:Array = arrayString.split(",");
var n:int=newArray.length;
while (n--)
{
    newArray[n]=Number(newArray[n])
    var obj:Object = new Object();
    obj.label = newArray[n];
    this.myDataGrid.addItem(obj );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrayString:String = myTextArea.text;
var newArray:Array = arrayString.split(",");
var n:int=newArray.length;

var dataProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

while (n--)
{
    newArray[n]=Number(newArray[n])
    var obj:Object = { label: newArray[n] };
    dataProvider.addItem(obj);
}

this.myDataGrid.dataProvider = dataProvider;
```